# Accessing a matrix in Matlab

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matrix, if-statement

Assume user input data as below. I define my matrix is cost. The matrix i created is 3 by 3 matrix. So the matrix should form like this:

```
cost = [c11 c12 c13            

         c21 c22 c23

         c31 c32 c33]
```

Since i want to display set of row, i do it like this :

```
c1 = cost(1,:); % it will become c1 = c11 c12 c13

c2 = cost(2,:); % it will become c2 = c21 c22 c23

c3 = cost(3,:); % it will become c3 = c31 c32 c33
```

Then i want the value in the matrix. I do it like this.

```
c11 = cost(1,1);

c12 = cost(1,2);

c13 = cost(1,3);

c21 = cost(2,1);

c22 = cost(2,2);

c23 = cost(2,3);

c31 = cost(3,1);

c32 = cost(3,2);

c33 = cost(3,3);
```

So this is the equation that i want to use for this type of matrix.

```
lambda = 
((8*c13*c23*c33*Pdt)+(4*c12*c23*c33)+(4*c13*c22*c33)+(4*c13*c23*c32)) ./ (4*c23*c33)+(4*c13*c33)+(4*c13*c23));
```

So my problem is, if i want to make 4 by 3 matrix, and it would generate a matrix like this:

```
cost = [c11 c12 c13            

         c21 c22 c23

         c31 c32 c33

         c41 c42 c43]
```

The equation that i want to use for this matrix(4 by 3) is quite different. So how im gonna do it? Do i need to use if else statement? or do while? Can anyone help me solve this? Can anyone create the code?

Comment: Your title should always describe the type of problem you are having, the SO community assume your are "Stuck with coding" because you posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you explicitly create the variables c11, c12, ...? Surely it would be easier to just access the matrix in your equation like this:

> lambda =
>   ((8*cost(1,3)*cost(2,3)*cost(3,3)*Pdt)+(4*cost(1,2)*cost(2,3)*cost(3,3)+(4*cost(1,3)*cost(2,2)*c(3,3))+(4*cost(1,3)*cost(2,3)*cost(3,2)) ./
>   (4*cost(2,3)*cost(3,3))+(4*cost(1,3)*cost(3,3))+(4*cost(1,3)*cost(2,3)));

For your question, yes, just use a simple if statment, like this:

> if size(cost,1) == 3
>
> ```
>   %equation for matrix size 3x3
> ```
>
> else
>
> ```
>   %equation for matriz size 4x3
> ```